# Folder transfer with scp command

Tags: linux, terminal, scp, file-transfer

I want to transfer my folder from my computer to server by using `scp` command. Folder structure like these : `FOLDER/SubFolders/*.json`. There are more than 1 `SubFolders`. Each of them has different `JSON` files. How can I transfer this `FOLDER` from my computer to server by using `scp`? I tried this :

`$ scp FOLDER server@server_address`

but I got this error:

`FOLDER: not a regular file`

Comment: use `scp -r FOLDER user@host:` -- don't omit the `-r` option (recursive) and the colon (`:`) after host.

Comment: @mosvy thank you! It is worked!